# FQL - Data fetched/unfeteched almost "randomly"

Tags: facebook-fql

Her'es the situation, I run the following FQL code (in the debugger currently) to search my stream for specific items:

`SELECT attachment,description,message 
FROM stream 
WHERE 
(source_id=me())
AND
strpos(message,'shakshuka') >=0`

Things are alright - I get results, woohoo. 
BUT (!) :

When I change the condition, to something that should be very simple-
 to support also my friends posts, suddenly.. I get nothing.
For example:

`SELECT attachment,description,message 
FROM stream 
WHERE 
(source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR source_id=me())
AND
strpos(message,'shakshuka') >=0`

I could run these twice but... why?!
I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with all considering limitations and FQL queries, after reading some posts @ FB dev forums,
I just added **LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0** to the end of the query and it works like magic.
I guess the tech guys @ Facebook need a little extra hand in all regarding to stable their own "SQL" version.